# When moving the camera in runtime in the game view using the keys wsad , why the camera is moving in diagonal directions?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I mean when pressing the W S A D for example pressing W instead making the camera moving straight up it's moving to the up and left the same time. same for all the other keys it's moving to two directions same time.

I'm calling the method from the Update

```
private void HandleCameraMovement()
    {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 moveDirection = new Vector3(horizontal, 0f, vertical);
        moveDirection.Normalize();

        transform.Translate(moveDirection * cameraMoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
    }
```

I tried also this before but same result:

```
private void HandleCameraMovement()
    {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 moveDirection = new Vector3(horizontal, 0f, vertical).normalized * cameraMoveSpeed;
        transform.Translate(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
    }
```

and also this:

```
private void HandleCameraMovement()
    {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 moveDirection = new Vector3(horizontal, 0f, vertical) * cameraMoveSpeed;
        transform.Translate(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
    }
```

Comment: What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: @shingo ok,  i found that if i set the camera rotation to X = 90 Y = 0 Z = 0 it will work fine with the keys WSAD,  but I want it to work fine also if the camera rotation is not 90,0,0 i want it work to be the same behaviour when the camera is at 90,0,0 rotation in any rotation even if the camera is 3,23,7,51 the behaviour should be always like if the camera rotation was 90,0,0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just want the camera to move along its own XY coordinate, so you need map the input values to XY and do not use `Space.World` (the default parameter is `Space.Self`).

```
Vector3 moveDirection = new Vector3(horizontal, vertical, 0f);
moveDirection.Normalize();
transform.Translate(moveDirection * cameraMoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```